# Renaming files of variable length in DOS

Tags: dos, windows-shell, file-rename, batch-rename

I'm trying to rename files that have `'@'` to `'_'`.
I understand that there is a straigt forward way of replacing the nth character in a file.

How do we rename files , if `@` symbol is present in different places in different files

For example, assuming the below files are present in a directory

```
 a@file.txt   
 asdf@kfi.png
 uiuydfjfk@kdi.txt
```

I want the output to be like this one

```
 a_file.txt
 asdf_kfi.png
 uiuydfjfk_kdi.txt
```

Is there anyway to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

This uses a helper batch file called repl.bat from - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855

It creates renfile.bat for you to examine for errors, and then execute.

```
dir *@* /b |repl "(.*)(@)(.*)" "ren \x22$&\x22 \x22$1_$3\x22" x >renfile.bat
```